# Kotlin: Function using = when() to return value(s)

Tags: kotlin

I recently discovered this nice syntax for a function that only returns a value based on the input:

```
fun getItem(value: Int): String = when (getPosition(value)) {
   0 -> "Zero"
   1 -> "One"
   2 -> "Two"
   else -> "Other"
}
```

Is it also possible to use ranges or <> operators?

I've tried doing things like:

```
>0 -> "Positive"
```

Which is not accepted, and

```
0-10 -> "Postively small"
```

is (naturally) seen as "0 minus 10" I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do some of these things, but not in the way you describe. For example you can use `is`, `in` and `==` like this:

```kotlin
val x = 10

when (x) {
    in 0..10 -> 1
    10 -> 2
    is Int -> 3
    else -> 4
}
```

but you can't use comparison operators (`<`, `>`). The reason for this is explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression). You can use arbitrary expressions, but `<` and `>` can't be overloaded so you can't do `greaterThan(x)`.

If you are missing some features from Kotlin you can always open a [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP) so at some point, it might get implemented!

Comment: Great! That does the trick; No need for <> in my case, so "between x and u" is perfect.